# How to scan my hard drive for problems?

Tags: hard-drive

I would need some help to find out if there is some problems with my hard drive. Could this be done by running Ubuntu from a dvd?

Kind regards, Victor

Answer (score 1):

You could try with booting from a live CD and

```
sudo apt install smartmontools
sudo smartctl --all /dev/YOUR_DISK
```

or the GUI version "gsmartcontrol".

Answer (score 0):

You can use **smartctl** to check for and enable SMART support

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools     
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | less
```

To enable SMART support (if it turn off) just type:

```
sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda
```

For more details and reference, please check Ubuntu Help (Wiki) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Disks utility from the menu and check the drive's SMART health status.  You can also run a self test on the drive.